# Apache Camel Saga configuration using LRA Coordinator

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-saga

Could someone help me understand how to configure Apache Camel Saga using LRA coordinator in Springboot. I tried through the documentation but unfortunately, the documentation is not that clear and I would need at least some sample code to understand how to execute this external coordinator using a specific image. If anybody has implemented it please share some docs or ways to configure the LRA specifically.

Answer (score 2):

What's the camel version you are using? You can use the `applicaion.yaml` like

```
camel:
  lra:
    enabled: true
    coordinator-url: http://localhost:8088
    local-participant-url: http://localhost:8080/context-path
```

Please check https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/eips/saga-eip.html#_using_the_lra_saga_service_in_spring_boot for more details.

In term of running a exteneral coordinator servers, you could think about https://quay.io/repository/jbosstm/lra-coordinator. And start it with command

```
docker run -i --rm -p 8088:8080 quay.io/jbosstm/lra-coordinator
```

To verify the lra-coordinator is working, please try

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8088/lra-coordinator/start
```

It should return something like `http://localhost:8088/lra-coordinator/0_ffffac110005_8bf3_640f2093_2` and use `curl` to retrieve the link you can get the current LRA transaction status.